# <example></example> XML comment tag: how to see it?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, intellisense, objectbrowser

I use Microsoft Visual Studio 2012.
When I put code examples into XML comments of C# classes/methods, I wonder: how will user that references my assemblies see that code example?

I tried to reference my own assembly, and the only way I found was: to look at assembly.xml file.
Can I settle Visual Studio or anything else to see those code examples?

Here is what I put into comments:

```
/// <summary>
/// This is my method example
/// </summary>
/// <example>
/// <code>
/// // Here is my code example. Call my method like this:
/// const int a = 10;
/// MethodExample(a);
/// </code>
/// </example>
public static void MethodExample(int parameter)
{
}
```

Here is what I get in IntelliSense:

[image]

Here is what I get in Object Browser:

[image]

Here is what I get in assembly.xml file:

[image]

What I'd like to get: see code examples in Object Browser and IntelliSense.

Comment: Perhaps the `<example>` tags are intended for use in generating documentation/specs.

Comment: I don't even think you can get them showing in IntelliSense with ReSharper, perhaps another addin could do it, but that's not really what `<example>` is for.

Comment: I‘m going to suggest this as a feature so Quick Info/IntelliSense shows this. The support for XML comments when hovering over something or pressing Ctrl+K, Ctrl+I is not great. I would love to see all of the XML comments, otherwise it‘s almost pointless to write them.

Comment: If anyone wants to vote on it https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/377459/quick-infointellisense-should-show-more-of-xml-com.html

Comment: [This article in 2018](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/using-code-example-tags-csharp-xml-documentation-comments) suggests that it might work as expected in VS Code.

Answer (score 11):

A number of XML comment tags appear in IntelliSense only as child elements of other tags. These tags, known as ChildCompletionList tags, are: c, code, example, list, listheader, para, paramref, see and see also.

```
/// <summary>
/// MethodExample the function that does it all...
/// <example>
/// <code>
/// <para/>// Here is my code example. Call my method like this:
/// <para/>const int a = 10;
/// <para/>MethodExample(a);
/// </code>
/// </example>
/// </summary>
```

Comment: What is the difference for end-user between this, and if I just put code inside summary without <example> and <code> tags?

Comment: The text for the <summary> tag is the only source of information about the type in IntelliSense.

Comment: In VS 2012, if I use <summary><example><code></code></example></summary> the text in the code element displays unformatted in intellisense and in the object browser.  Very ugly.

Comment: -1 This is not true with regards to the <example> tag -- in the MSDN documentation, <example> is listed as a separate top-level element, side-by-side with <summary>. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/example

Comment: @jim31415 RE "only source of information" -- do you have a link or reference where this is stated?

Comment: @CJBS, "The <summary> tag is used by IntelliSense inside Visual Studio to display additional information about a type or member." So, if you want example usage information to display in intellisense, you would need to include that information in the <summary> block. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/how-to-use-the-xml-documentation-features

Answer (score 3):

If your **not seeing XML commments in IntelliSense or they're not updating** after you edit them try:

1. **Not seeing**: be sure everything is enclosed in the **<summary>  element**.
   ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/xmldoc/recommended-tags
2. **Not updating**: **close & reopen solution** (this seems to work pretty consistently)

VS Ent 2019 (16.10.4)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30131548)